# Some "ObjectId" is not getting replaced

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

I am converting the mongodb's document `_id`

`from :` `"_id" : ObjectId("5c09b6002351d50e100c5f6c"),`

`To:` `"_id" : "5c09b6002351d50e100c5f6c",`
I am using the regex  `text.replace(/ObjectId\((.*)\)/gi,"$1");`

Issue is some `ObjectId` gets converted but some doesn't gets converted,don't know why..

`small example code of what i am doing:`

```
var fs=require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('./abc.json');      
str = data.toString()
str = str.replace(/ObjectId\((.*)\)/g,"$1");
fs.writeFile('str','data.json');
```

`note:` I have exported the input file using Studio 3T

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a problem, then you used regex and now you have two problems.

Comment: you mean to say the input file itself has an issue? @cgTag

Comment: No, it's an old saying :) https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `.*` also matches some whole "ObjectId(...)" expressions.

A solution is to use a non greedy group:

```
text.replace(/ObjectId\((.*?)\)/gi,"$1");
```

A better (more performant) one is to make it explicit if you can:

```
text.replace(/ObjectId\(("[^"]*")\)/gi,"$1");
```

Comment: @PrabhatMishra can you build [a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: @PrabhatMishra yes but still no way to check or reproduce your problem.

Comment: i have exported this file using Studio 3T you can try that to reproduce the problem..@Denys